# How do I isolate a certain state from a topjson file by id?

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I am using D3 to create a map of the united states and overlay it with the congressional districts. I used much of the code in Mike Bostock's [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4657115) to get started. I am now trying to make it possible for the user to show just one state when selected. I tried his example of zooming but that isn't working well. I am using Mike's us.json file(after I removed the counties data that I don't need). How can I use D3 to parse that file for only a certain state. I see each state has an id associated with it. For example...

`{"type":"Topology","objects":{"states":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"MultiPolygon","id":2,"arcs":[[[9426]],[[9427]],`

I assume that id is the state fips code.

Here is a snippet of my code using the datum function of D3. As you can see I am successfully pulling out the state id:

```
console.log(us.objects.states.geometries[0].id);
svg.append("defs").append("path")
     .attr("id", "land")
     .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
     .attr("d", path);
```

Comment: You would have to filter everything but the state you're interested in before passing the data to `.datum()`.

Comment: right, that is what i don't know how to do! can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Hmmm, something like `us.objects.states.filter(function(d) { return d.geometries[0].id == stateID; })`.